# Unable to use NPM in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-14.04

I am unable to use NPM. Whenever I type npm -v or npm install it shoe error. Please find it  below as

**bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: /usr/local/bin/node: bad interpreter: No such file or directory**

I tried installing npm and after install it says a newer version is already installed.But wen I run any npm specific command it still throws that same error.

I was previously using node pre version 11.x.x, however due to some compatibility issues I had to remove it and use the default nodejs that comes with Ubuntu LTS 14.04

Please help me in finding the root cause and how can I make npm work.

Comment: I think that on Ubuntu, the Node.js interpreter is called `nodejs` and not `node` (which is the reason why running `npm` triggers the error that `/usr/local/bin/node` doesn't exist). I would think that a properly installed `npm` (through Ubuntu's package mechanism) would point to that. Try reinstalling it: `[sudo] apt-get --reinstall npm`

Comment: @robertklep you probably want to avoid using `apt-get` to install node / npm, installing from source is usually the best way to go.

Comment: @BrendanAshworth agreed, although the user posted they are using the default nodejs that comes with Ubuntu and I'm trying to give them a solution that would fit that situation :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try instead:

```
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

That will install the last `npm`.

Comment: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   193  100   193    0     0    162      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   162
sh: 1: cannot open html: No such file
sh: 2: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

I am getting this.

Comment: curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
I had to add -L before the url.

It now says
-->
npm cannot be installed without nodejs.
Install node first, and then try again.

Maybe node is installed, but not in the PATH?
Note that running as sudo can change envs.

Comment: `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -`  according to [their wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)